# Typescript Error Cannot find name 'cordova'

Tags: ionic3

I am using ionic3 right now, there is no declaration.d.ts file in ionic3. So i couldn't declare cordova in that file. Can anyone help to solve the problem in ionic3 way? Thank you so much!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  /*Cordova add */
  wikitudePlugin: any;
  requiredFeatures = [ "2d_tracking", "geo" ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.wikitudePlugin = cordova.require("com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin.WikitudePlugin");
      this.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(this.onDeviceSupported, this.onDeviceNotSupported, this.requiredFeatures);
      console.log('The wikitude object: ', this.wikitudePlugin);
      console.log('The wikitude test method: ',this.wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported);
    });
  }
  onDeviceSupported () {
    console.log('device supported');
  }

  onDeviceNotSupported () {
    console.log('device not supported');
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am getting the same error while I am using inAppbrowser cordova plugin in my Angular 13 project. cordova.InAppBrowser.open('URL', '_blank'); I am using this line in one of the components in my app